# Determine the languages for the given alphabet

Tags: discrete-mathematics, self-learning, formal-languages

For the alphabet $\sum = \{0,1\}, let A,B,C \subseteq \sum^*$ be the languages below.

$i. A = \{1, 0, 00, 11, 000, 111, 0000, 1111\}$

$ii. B = \{w \in \sum^*|||w|| \ge 2 \}$

$ii. C = \{w \in \sum^*|||w|| \le 2 \}$

Note: ||w|| is the length of the word w.

Determine the following languages of $\sum^*$:

a. $A \cap B$

b. $A \cap C$

c. $B \cup C$

d. $A \Delta B$

For $A \cap B$ I have: $w \in \sum^*$ such that $w \ge 2$, thus $A \cap B = 00, 11, 000, 111, 0000, 1111$. I am not sure if I am doing this right so any help is appreciated.

I completed the answers for $A \cap C$ and $B \cup C$ in a similar manner so I won't put the workings here.

I am completely stuck on $A \Delta B$. I am not sure how to use this character $\Delta$ in this exercise so any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Tony

Comment: $A \Delta B$ usually denotes exclusive-or, i.e. $(A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A)$. I'm sure you can complete the rest of the answer in a similar manner, so I won't put the workings here.

Comment: According to my book $A \Delta B$ is equivalent to $A \cup B$. Is this what you meant? (In your example you use the symbol \, but I don't know what that means; it is not in the list of symbols that my book uses). So, if $A \Delta B$ is equivalent to $A \cup B$ do I now have $A \cup B$ = $(00|11), (000|111), (0000|1111)$? The $|$ denotes or.

Comment: I should also point out that my book also uses $\Delta$ to denote a finite set of non-terminal symbols. This is why I became confused as to how to use it here.

Comment: Symbol $\setminus$ is the set difference, that is, $X \setminus Y = X \cap Y^c$ where $Y^c$ denotes the complement of $Y$. So $A\Delta B$ is in that notation $(A \cap B^c) \cup (B \cap A^c)$. If $\Delta$ is equivalent to $\cup$, why use the different symbol? My hypothesis is that in your example $A$ and $B$ were disjoint, because then these really are equivalent. However, in general, they are not.

Comment: Before I continue, I want to ask if I am on the correct track. Did I answer $A \cap B$ correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You answered $A \cap B$ correctly. The $\triangle$ operator on sets is called the symmetric difference operator. You only keep elements in exactly one of the sets. When dealing with binary values, the symmetric difference is analogous to the exclusive-or operator (or addition modulo 2).

Given disjoint sets, symmetric difference is equivalent to union, as neither sets share common elements, so nothing is removed.

Comment: I've been doing some thinking on this and I am wondering if I should end my answer with: For $A \cap B$ I have: $w \in \sum^*$ such that $w \ge 2$, thus $A \cap B = 00, 11, 000, 111, 0000, 1111$, or should I conclude with, The language of $\sum = \{00^n | 1 \le n \le 4\} \cap \{11^n | 1 \le n \le 4\}$

Comment: The language $\Sigma = \{00^{n} : 1 \leq n \leq 4\} \cap \{11^{n} 1 \leq n \leq 4 \} = \emptyset$. If you put set brackets around your first answer, that would be fine. Also, $11^{4} = 11111$.